# Iterating through dictionary, finding duplicate entries and interpolating across duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was given a table where there are duplicate times for and duplicate positions that vary in repetition through the table but with unique ffid values in the first column. I'm trying to go through the table grouping identical times and interpolating the position from first time/position of that group to the next. Here is an example...

```
FFID    X   Y   YEAR    DAY HOUR    MINUTE  SECOND
2   585046.024  4368375.389 2019    277 18  38  37
3   585046.024  4368375.389 2019    277 18  38  37
4   585046.024  4368375.389 2019    277 18  38  37
5   585046.024  4368375.389 2019    277 18  38  37
6   585046.024  4368375.389 2019    277 18  38  37
7   585044.853  4368373.899 2019    277 18  38  38
8   585044.853  4368373.899 2019    277 18  38  38
9   585044.853  4368373.899 2019    277 18  38  38
10  585044.853  4368373.899 2019    277 18  38  38
11  585044.853  4368373.899 2019    277 18  38  38
12  585044.853  4368373.899 2019    277 18  38  38
13  585043.674  4368372.383 2019    277 18  38  39
14  585043.674  4368372.383 2019    277 18  38  39
15  585043.674  4368372.383 2019    277 18  38  39
16  585043.674  4368372.383 2019    277 18  38  39
17  585043.674  4368372.383 2019    277 18  38  39
18  585043.674  4368372.383 2019    277 18  38  39
```

I'm quite new to python and a little out of my depth on this one. But I've got the data in as dictionaries with the ffid and time grouped as my key and the XY positions as my value. Like this...

```
'1 279 2:47:50.0':['590867.803', '4388318.746']
```

I was trying to break the items down into a list and compare the values against each other, and rebuild the dictionary as I do the interpolation. The start of my code...

```
#%% Sort list and interpolate across identical values
    x=0
    sbp_int = dict()
    rows = [s_ffid[0], s_jd[0], s_hr[0], s_mm[0], s_ss[0], s_X[0], s_Y[0]]
    for r in range(1,len(sbp_lst)):
        rows = [s_ffid[r], s_jd[r], s_hr[r], s_mm[r], s_ss[r], s_X[r], s_Y[r]]
        crnt= [item[r] for item in sbp_lst]
        prev= [item[r-1] for item in sbp_lst]
        if crnt[1:5] == prev[1:5]:
            temp = str(crnt[0])+' '+str(crnt[1])+' '+str(crnt[2])+':'+str(crnt[3])+':'+str(crnt[4])
            sbp_int[temp]=[crnt[5], crnt[6]]
```

But I'm starting to think I'm approaching this the wrong way and looking for suggestions.

My intended result would look something like this...full disclosure I only eyeballed the interpolation, but a linear interpolation is what I'm trying for.

```
FFID    X   Y   YEAR    DAY HOUR    MINUTE  SECOND
2   585046.024  4368375.389 2019    277 18  38  37
3   585045.774  4368375.489 2019    277 18  38  37
4   585045.524  4368375.589 2019    277 18  38  37
5   585045.274  4368375.689 2019    277 18  38  37
6   585045.024  4368375.789 2019    277 18  38  37
7   585044.853  4368373.899 2019    277 18  38  38
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What's the part that is repeated and should be unique? From your question, it seems you want one row per "time" - interpreted as (year,day,hour,min,sec), but in your output sample you have five lines with the same time...

Comment: (Also, ditch the dictionaries and have a look at [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/))

Comment: @GPhilo sorry for the confusion. I need the time rows to remain the same, but have the XYs be unique, interpolated up to the next time/position change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution to your problem:

1. I generate a defaultdict, with distinct dates as keys and   "FFID" list as values
2. an other dict with FFID as keys and a corresponding tuple of x, y points as values.

With these, I iterate through the distinct dates, and then simply apply a linear interpolation for each x, y values, using the number of FFID values per date to determine the number of steps.

Here is the script:

```
import collections

input = """
FFID    X   Y   YEAR    DAY HOUR    MINUTE  SECOND
2   585046.024  4368375.389 2019    277 18  38  37
3   585046.024  4368375.389 2019    277 18  38  37
4   585046.024  4368375.389 2019    277 18  38  37
5   585046.024  4368375.389 2019    277 18  38  37
6   585046.024  4368375.389 2019    277 18  38  37
7   585044.853  4368373.899 2019    277 18  38  38
8   585044.853  4368373.899 2019    277 18  38  38
9   585044.853  4368373.899 2019    277 18  38  38
10  585044.853  4368373.899 2019    277 18  38  38
11  585044.853  4368373.899 2019    277 18  38  38
12  585044.853  4368373.899 2019    277 18  38  38
13  585043.674  4368372.383 2019    277 18  38  39
14  585043.674  4368372.383 2019    277 18  38  39
15  585043.674  4368372.383 2019    277 18  38  39
16  585043.674  4368372.383 2019    277 18  38  39
17  585043.674  4368372.383 2019    277 18  38  39
18  585043.674  4368372.383 2019    277 18  38  39
"""

FFID = slice(0, 2)
X = slice(4, 14)
Y = slice(16, 26)
DATE = slice(28, 50)
line_items = input.split('\n')[2:-1]

distinct_date = collections.defaultdict(list)
points_dict = {}

for item in line_items:
    distinct_date[item[DATE]].append(item[FFID])
    points_dict[item[FFID]] = (float(item[X]), float(item[Y]))

date_arr = [k for k in distinct_date.keys()]

for i in range(len(date_arr) - 1):
    x0, y0 = points_dict[distinct_date[date_arr[i]][0]]
    x1, y1 = points_dict[distinct_date[date_arr[i + 1]][0]]
    steps = range(len(distinct_date[date_arr[i]]))
    interpolated = [(step / len(steps) * (x1 - x0) + x0, step / len(steps) * (y1 - y0) + y1) for step in steps]
    for j in steps:
        ffid_val = distinct_date[date_arr[i]][j]
        print(f'{ffid_val}  {interpolated[j][0]:.3f}  {interpolated[j][1]:.3f}  {date_arr[i]}')
```

Let me know if your need more detailed explanations.

Comment: thanks for taking the time! I've been working on it and have a semi-working solution (I'll post once I've got this one little kink worked out). But I'll step through your code and see if it works, then probably implement some of the libraries/methods you used. Cheers!